# How to take offline a database in Oracle?

Tags: oracle

**We have direct functionality of **Take Offline** to SQL**
[image: In SQL we have option like Take Offline like below image]

**but how to do same functionality in Oracle Sql Developer**

[image]

Comment: `alter pluggable database .... close immediate;`

Comment: You should learn how to do those commands in sqlplus. Why do you want to take the database offline? If you want an rman warm backup then you can shutdown immediate; and startup mount; from sqlplus. As other have suggested alter pluggable database ... close immediate; is good if you want to copy databases to a new instance. You might want to start with what is it that you are trying to accomplish. Because the answer will change based on what you are doing.

Answer (score 4):

Open a DBA connection instead of a regular connection (View / DBA to display the DBA panel), where you can use the `Modify State` menu:

[image]